# Lost the function in history.push after reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
 history.push({
      pathname:
        vaccineTaken == "Yes" ||
        (vaccineTaken == 1 ? "/vaccination" : "/no-vaccine"),
      state: data,
      onCancel: getExistingSurvey, // This is function
});
```

> the attribute get cleared after reloading the tab, i have tried to do
> `state:{ onCancel: getExistingSurvey}`
> but it gives an error

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because when you reload, you are directly calling the route. which in turn will not have the history object from before the reload.
it is a bad practice to put state in history. use Proper State management like redux or react hooks.